# Find when the values of a pandas.Series change by at least x

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bigdata

I have a time series s stored as a pandas.Series and I need to find when the value tracked by the time series changes by at least x.

In pseudocode:

```
print s(0)
s*=s(0)
for all t in ]t, t_max]:
    if |s(t)-s*| > x:
        s* = s(t)
        print s*
```

Naively, this can be coded in Python as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

def find_changes(s, x):

    changes = []
    s_last = None

    for index, value in s.iteritems():

        if s_last is None:
            s_last = value 

        if value-s_last > x or s_last-value > x:
            changes += [index, value]
            s_last = value
    return changes
```

My data set is large, so I can't just use the method above. Moreover, I cannot use Cython or Numba due to limitations of the framework I will run this on. I can (and plan to) use pandas and NumPy.

I'm looking for some guidance on what NumPy vectorized/optimized methods to use and how.

Thanks!

EDIT: Changed code to match pseudocode.

Comment: The problem has this strong linearity internally, in the sense that there's no indication as to where the next threshold would be until you see it. So it would be very interesting to see a parallel/vectorized solution.

Comment: Also, there are couple of things I'm not so sure about: 1. Your pseudocode seems to differ to your Python code. 2. How large your data is, because, even the Python code can process a few billion of rows in at most couple of minutes.

Comment: @QuangHoang I fixed the code to match the pseudocode, must have been a copy-paste error when I wrote the OP. The data set has ~ 100 GB.

Comment: Memory size is irrelevant unless you need to do so for every column. Otherwise it’s the number of row that is important.

Comment: @dd_rlwll Single file 100GB? How do you store the original data?

Comment: @knh190 We're getting out of scope but the data are stored in HDF5.

Comment: @QuangHoang It's a single column (plus the index).

Comment: @dd_rlwll Then simply loop through the group without loading the whole file into memory: http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/group.html#group

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I am understanding you correctly, but here is how I interpreted the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Our series of data.

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10), columns = ['value'])

# The threshold.

threshold = .33

# For each point t, grab t - 1. 

data['value_shifted'] = data['value'].shift(1)

# Absolute difference of t and t - 1.

data['abs_change'] = abs(data['value'] - data['value_shifted'])

# Test against the threshold.

data['change_exceeds_threshold'] = np.where(data['abs_change'] > threshold, 1, 0)

print(data)
```

Giving:

```
      value  value_shifted  abs_change  change_exceeds_threshold
0  0.005382            NaN         NaN                         0
1  0.060954       0.005382    0.055573                         0
2  0.090456       0.060954    0.029502                         0
3  0.603118       0.090456    0.512661                         1
4  0.178681       0.603118    0.424436                         1
5  0.597814       0.178681    0.419133                         1
6  0.976092       0.597814    0.378278                         1
7  0.660010       0.976092    0.316082                         0
8  0.805768       0.660010    0.145758                         0
9  0.698369       0.805768    0.107400                         0
```

Comment: The solution is neat, but I think it's different from the pseudo code.

Comment: He doesn't simply want to compare to the previous point, but to all the point since last violation. Imagine if the series is increasing, then we would be looking at `cumsum()` of `diff()` with reset.

Comment: This seems to be the same as applying diff() and comparing the new column to a threshold. It's not what I'm looking after.

Comment: @QuangHoang You got it right. Unfortunately, the series is not monotonous.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the pseudo code can be vectorized because the next state of `s*` is dependent on the last state. There's a pure python solution (1 iteration):

```py
import random
import pandas as pd

s = [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(100)]
res = [] # record changes
thres = 20

ss = s[0]
for i in range(len(s)):
    if abs(s[i] - ss) > thres:
        ss = s[i]
        res.append([i, s[i]])

df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['value'])
```

I think there's no way to run faster than O(N) in this case.

Comment: I have spent a few hours on this problem and could not beat O(N) myself. However, I was hoping the loop could be optimized through a non-trivial combination of NumPy functions. If nothing pans out I may have no option but to install Cython.

Comment: @dd_rlwll No solution can be better than O(N), even functions provided by numpy will not save you. They can be worse if you count the object creating overheads.

Comment: Especially in this case with 100GB data, you can't create such large dataframe. You should use smaller chunks and flush results to disk per certain loops.

Comment: I don't want to go into details about the structure (or storage) of the data but it is already read in chunks and the results flushed at periodic intervals. Just in case my message above wasn't clear, I do know the solution won't scale better than O(N). This doesn't mean that each loop operation can't be optimized to run much faster than my naive code version in the OP.

Comment: Chunk or not, it seems like the naive approach works. And it isn’t that time consuming. I bet the time you spent on stackoverflow on this question is more than enough to run that algorithm several times.