Pandas rate limit output based on minimum change in a column
I have a dataframe which has column t which is a monotonically increasing integer - I want to filter the dataframe such that I choose as many rows as I can but in the OUTPUT i never have any two rows where t - t.shift(1) <= 10 (and always including the first row of the input dataframe in the output).  This is different than df[df['t'].diff().fillna(20) >= 10] because I might have a string of input rows where t is  5 apart and just taking the diff  would on the input would throw out all of them.
In inefficient pseudocode it would be something like:
last_chosen = None
inds = []
for i, t in enumerate(df['t']):
    if last_chosen is None or t - last_chosen >= 10:
        last_chosen = t
        inds.append(df.index[i])

new_df = df[inds]

Is there any efficient way to do this?
Edit:  Minimal example:

def filt(df, gap=10):
    last_chosen = None
    inds = []
    for i, t in enumerate(df['t']):
        if last_chosen is None or t - last_chosen >= gap:
            last_chosen = t
            inds.append(df.index[i])

    return df.loc[inds]
    


d = pd.DataFrame(dict(
     t = [5, 7, 9, 10, 15, 20, 30, 45, 50, 55, 60, 70]))

(d['t'][d['t'].diff().fillna(10) >= 10])  # gives [5, 30, 45, 70]

filt(d)['t'] # gives [5, 15, 30, 45, 55, 70] which is desired



Can you provide a [mre] (input + expected output) for clarity?

An example would help. Especially one that shows what you've tried, what result it gave, and how that differs from what you want. Because I can't see why "a string of input rows where t is 5 apart" would be thrown out by taking the diff.

IIUC, you can't vectorize this operation. You can use numba to speed this up

It looks like @mozway is right - this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738163/find-when-the-values-of-a-pandas-series-change-by-at-least-x  which as far as I can tell the only solution was a naive loop

As mentioned earlier in comments, you cannot vectorize this operation. Since the presence of a value depends on the fate of previous values, an iterative process is needed, i.e. a loop.
Your code is thus perfectly fine, however you can improve its speed greatly using numba. You need to tweak a bit the code for numba to accept the input (as numpy array):
from numba import jit

@jit
def numba_filt(a, gap=10):
    last_chosen = None
    inds = []
    for i, t in enumerate(a):
        if last_chosen is None or t - last_chosen >= gap:
            last_chosen = t
            inds.append(i)

    return inds

def filt(df, gap=10, col='t'):
    return df.iloc[numba_filt(df[col].to_numpy(), gap=gap)]

filt(d)['t']

Output:
0      5
4     15
6     30
7     45
9     55
11    70
Name: t, dtype: int64

timings
Testing this on 2M rows we get a ~5x increase in speed.
# python loop
303 ms ± 6.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# numba
60.9 ms ± 682 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Used input:
df = pd.DataFrame({'t': np.sort(np.random.choice(10_000_000, 2_000_000, replace=False))})


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'t': [5, 7, 9, 10, 15, 20, 30, 45, 50, 55, 60, 70]})
print(df)
gap = 10
t_values = df['t'].values
chosen = np.zeros(len(t_values),dtype= bool)
chosen[0] = True
last_chosen_value= t_values[0]
while True :
    next_value = last_chosen_value + gap
    next_index = np.searchsorted(t_values,next_value, side ='left')
    if next_index >= len(t_values) :break
    chosen[next_index] =True
    last_chosen_value = t_values[next_index]
    print("last_chosen_value :",last_chosen_value)
 
res = df[chosen] 
print(res)  
'''
     t
0    5
4   15
6   30
7   45
9   55
11  70
'''  

